# Creating a circular UIView with size set by AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UIView inside a UICollectionViewCell. The inner view is set to be 0.75 of the width and height of the cell and centred both horizontally and vertically.

The cells get their size from a UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, where the size is set to 1/3 of the screen width.

I know how to create a circular view when the width is fixed. However, I am not quite sure where to apply the corner radius in order to make this work properly.

I've tried setting the radius inside the cell's `awakeFromNib` and `layoutSubviews`, but in both cases the width of the inner view is calculated using the cell's size set in Interface Builder.

Also, I've already tried setting the cell's size to both dynamic and custom in IB.

Here's my latest attempt using `layoutSubviews`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    bottomView.layer.cornerRadius = bottomView.bounds.width / 2
}
```

EDIT: Apparently, the radius is calculated correctly for cells that are not visible initially, i.e. below the fold. The initially visible cells still have the wrong radius.